# Ode Golf - Letter Deletions

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a dictionary file (a text file containing a word or phrase on each line, with possible punctuation but no numbers; lines are alphabetized), you must output each combination of words where one letter can be removed from a word to make another; the removed letter should be encased in parentheses.

For example, the input

```
cat
cart
code
golf
ode
verify
versify
```

should give an output of

```
ca(r)t
(c)ode
ver(s)ify
```

Multiple ways to get the same pair must only be displayed once. You can output `scra(p)ped` or `scrap(p)ed`, but not both.

The output should be ordered *alphabetically* by the longer entry;

```
mart
mar
mat
ma
```

should have an output of

```
ma(r)
ma(t)
ma(r)t
mar(t)
```

and the latter two could be in either order.

The dictionary file may include capitalizations, spaces, hyphens, or apostrophes; these should be ignored. For instance,

```
inlay 
in-play
```

should produce `in(p)lay`. Your output should all be in the same case. Extra whitespace is allowed.

Input can be STDIN or from a file; it is separated by newlines.
Output can be return value of a function or STDOUT (or written to a file if you wanted).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

(This is my first challenge on PPCG - let me know if I've done anything wrong and I'll fix it.)

Comment: What should be the output for `mart mar mat ma`? Would it be `mar(t) ma(r)t ma(r) ma(t)`?

Comment: @Sp: Forgot to specify the order - edited to clarify.

Comment: In the first example the word golf isn't in the output. Is that because it's a word that doesn't have other combinations?

Comment: @Luk: Yep! For most dictionary files, there will be a lot of words that don't make other words at all - those shouldn't appear anywhere in the output.

Comment: Since this is a dictionairy, can we assume the list is already sorted?

Comment: @Luk: Yes - I said that in the parentheses at the start, but it was worded in a weird way. Edited to clarify.

Comment: What about allowing a function with a (big) string parameter, returning the requested output as a string array? This put the focus on the algorithm, avoiding the need to manage file I/O.

Comment: @edc65 The Ruby answers already take an `Array` as input

Comment: @zozo: That title was completely intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Perl -an0, 101+3 bytes

```
@F=sort{length$a<=>length$b}map{s/\W//g;lc}@F;map{$`.$'~~@F?print"$`($1)$'\n":$\while/(.)(?!\1)/g}@F;
```

where

- `@F` is the dictionary, stored in an array, provided by runtime flag magic. *(b-oost, BoO#@%@#$%$#@T)*
- `map{s/\W//g;lc}@F` removes all symbols from the words and turns everything lowercase. *(boost, boot)*
- `sort{length$b<=>length$a}` sorts on length. *(boot, boost)*
- `map{ (...) while/(.)(?!\1)/g}@F` matches all characters that aren't followed up by the same character *([b]oot, bo[o]t,boo[t],...)*
- `` print"$`($1)$'\n" `` prints the parts that precede, parenthesize, and succeed a match... *(boo(s)t)*
- `` if $`.$'~~@F `` ...if the concatenation of everything before and after the match is in the dictionary. *([boo]s[t])*

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 225

A function with a string parameter, no input from file. I asked OP if this could be valid.

Test running the snippet in an EcmaScript 6 compliant browser (implementing arrow functions, template string, spread operator - Firefox, maybe Safari or MS Edge, not Chrome)

```js
f=t=>t.split`
`.map(w=>(d[k=w.replace(/\W/g,'').toLowerCase()]={},k),d={},r=[]).map(w=>[...w].map((c,i,v)=>(d[v[i]='',x=v.join``]&&!d[x][w]&&r.push(d[x][w]=(v[i]=`(${c})`,v.join``)),v[i]=c)))&&r.sort((a,b)=>a.length-b.length)

// LESS GOLFED

Q=t=>{
  // convert to canonical form and put in a dictionary
  // each value in the dictionary is an hashtable tha will store the list
  // of words that can generate the current word, removing a letter
  d={},
  t=t.split`\n`.map(w=>(k=w.replace(/\W/g,'').toLowerCase(),d[k]={},k))
  r=[], // result array 
  t.forEach(w =>
    [...w].forEach((c,i,v)=>( // for each letter in word, try to remove
      v[i]='', x=v.join``, // build string with missing letter
      v[i]='('+c+')', y=v.join``, // and build string with brackets
      v[i]=c, // restore the current letter
      d[x] && // if the word with removed letter is present in the dictionary
      !d[x][w] && // and not already from the same generating word
         r.push(d[x][w]=y) // update dictionary and add word to result array
    ))
  )
  return r.sort((a,b)=>a.length-b.length) // sort result by length
}  

// TEST
function test() { R.innerHTML=f(I.value) }
```

```css
textarea { height: 20em }
```

```html
Test <button onclick="test()">-></button>
<span id=R></span>
<br><textarea id=I>cat
cart
code
golf
node
scraped
scrapped
verify
versify
mart
mar
mat
ma</textarea>
```

Comment: @ETHproductions right, thx

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 173

```rb
->d{o=[]
c={}
d=d.sort_by{|w|[w.size,w]}.map{|w|w=w.upcase.gsub /[^A-Z]/,''
c[w]=l=1
w.size.times{|i|p,x,s=w[0...i],w[i],w[i+1..-1]
c[p+s]&&l!=x&&o<<p+"(#{w[i]})"+s
l=x}}
o}
```

Test it here: http://ideone.com/86avbe

Readable version here: http://ideone.com/ynFItB

Comment: On mobile so I can't test right now - could you add a test case for the SCRAPPED/SCRAPED one?

Comment: @Deusovi That case does not work correctly. I'm fixing it now...

Comment: @Deusovi Updated!

Comment: This answer does not provide correct output for e.g. the `['jacklantern','jackslantern','jack-o-lantern']` dict.

Comment: @14mRh4X0r I think the program returns the correct result for that test case (`["JACK(S)LANTERN", "JACK(O)LANTERN"]`). What do you think?

Comment: @w0lf According to the question, it has to be ordered alphabetically after length

Comment: @14mRh4X0r can't find that request in the question ... `The output should be ordered by the longer entry;` ... `and the latter two could be in either order.`

Comment: @edc65 `the latter two` exactly, so not the first two, which are in alphabetical order.

Comment: @14mRh4X0r then again: I can't find that request in the question. The order of the first two is not explicitly specified. I'll wait for a specification by OP

Comment: @edc65 Fair enough; let's wait for clarification.
To lighten the mood a bit: @w0lf You can shorten your answer by using `[-' ]` instead of `[^A-Z]`, the question states that you should (only) ignore those characters, beside the capitalisation

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 211

I decided I'd take a different approach to solve this, using regex.

```ruby
->d{o=[]
d.map{|x|x.upcase!.gsub! /[-' ]/,''}
d.map{|x|(x.size+1).times{|i|o+=d.map{|w|w.b.sub! /(#{x[0...i]})(.)(#{x[i..-1]})/,'\1(\2)\3'if w[i]!=w[i+1]}}}
o.compact.sort_by{|w|[w.size,w.gsub(/[()]/,'')]}.uniq}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 210

The code loads the input in an sorted array, and checks for each value against all values in the array that are 1 byte longer.

```
map{@W=split//,$w=$_;map{@X=split//,$x=$_;if(@W+1==@X){$i=0;while($W[$i]eq$X[$i]&&$i<@W){$i++}$c=$X[$i];$e=substr($w,$i);print substr($w,0,$i)."($c)$e\n",if substr($x,$i+1)eq$e}}@D}@D=sort(map{s/[^\w]//g;lc}<>)
```

#### Test

```
$ perl dictionairy_same_words.pl dictionairywords.txt
ca(r)t
in(p)lay
ma(r)
ma(t)
mar(t)
ma(r)t
(c)ode
ver(s)ify
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 201 bytes

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char
a#(b:c)=(a,b,c)
g a=[l++'(':m:')':n|x<-a,((l,m,n):_)<-[[o|o@(i,j,k)<-zipWith(#)(inits x)$init$tails x,elem(i++k)a]]]
f=sortOn length.g.map(filter isLetter.map toLower)
```

I'm not sure what input format is allowed. `f` takes a list of strings. If only a single string (with nl separated words) is allowed, add `.lines` to `f` (+6 bytes).

Usage example:

```
f ["cat","cart","code","golf","od-e","verify","versify","on","s-o-n","Scrapped","scraped"]

["(s)on","ca(r)t","(c)ode","ver(s)ify","scra(p)ped"]
```

How it works: turn every word to lowercase and keep only the letters. Split every word `x` into two parts at every possible position and make triples `(i,j,k)` where `i` is the first part, `j` is the first character of the second part and `k` is the tail of the second part. Keep the triples where `i++k` also appears in the word list. If this list is non-empty, take the first element, call it `(l,m,n)`. Turn all those list heads into the required output format by surrounding `m` with `()` and putting it between `l` and `n`.